# How to create Billing and payments invoice report in Meta API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Through the Facebook Business manager webpage, I can hit "Create report" and choose the parameters to generate a report.

I'd like to either:

- Do the same as above, through the API (ideal)
- Get the Invoices listed in the above page as CSV if the first option is not possible

I've tried hitting the /business_invoices endpoint and managed to download the PDF version of the invoice, which is not ideal.
I haven't managed to find an endpoint that would allow me to generate an equivalent report as the one I mentioned.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.